# Javascript regex for date string modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for regex for javascript function .replace

String I have is 2015-01-05 (date is always changing) and the result I want be is 15 as two last digits of year, What i thought to do was to remove - with `/\D/g` and then remove first two number and last four if its possible...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How about a find `\d{2}(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})` replace `$1` ?

Comment: Generally speaking: this place here is not "get me the codez". It's more about (in your case): "my regex does not return what I intended it should"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that, just take the needed chars by index :

```
var number = +yourstring.slice(2,4);
```

Now, suppose you want to use a regular expression, you may use

```
var number = +yourstring.match(/\d{2}(\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date('2015-01-05');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Alternatively, you can do it natively like this:

```
var dateAr = '2015-01-05'.split('-');
var newDate = dateAr[0] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[2];
var year = dateAr[0].substring(2, 4);//print year
```